# How to convert space separated file to tab delimited file in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two data files, viz., 'fin.dat' and 'shape.dat'. I want to format 'shape.dat' just the way the 'fin.dat' is written with Python. The files can be found here https://easyupload.io/m/h94wd3.
The snippets of the data structures are given here [fin.dat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWyUj.png),[shape.dat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIqX3.png). Please help me doing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('shape.dat') as fin, open('new.dat', 'w') as fout:
#to have data in separate columns from a single column
for line in fin:
    fout.write(line.replace('\t', ','))
```

Hi Hirak try the code above. It worked in my system.
[Here is output after operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf2Gu.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).